# How to Clone Menu Items for TPopupMenu?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I want to clone an entire TMenuItem with it's children to another TPopupMenu.
Here is a [nice code](http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.vcl.components.using/200809/080907220.html):

```
function CloneMenuItem(SourceItem: TMenuItem): TMenuItem;
var
  I: Integer;
Begin
  with SourceItem do
  Begin
    Result := NewItem(Caption, Shortcut, Checked, Enabled, OnClick, HelpContext, Name + 'Copy');
    for I := 0 To Count - 1 do
      Result.Add(CloneMenuItem(Items[I]));
  end;
end;
```

The following works just fine (b1 is a PopupMenu1.TMenuItem with sub menus):

```
PopupMenu2.Items.Add(CloneMenuItem(b1));
```

The problem is that I can't clone an *entire* TPopupMenu if the SourceItem is the root item.
e.g :

```
PopupMenu2.Items.Add(CloneMenuItem(PopupMenu1.Items));
```

Wont work. All I can *see* is 1 Item, as if it was a separator.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot clone the `TPopupMenu.Items` like that.  Even though `TPopupMenu.Items` is a `TMenuItem` object, it is not an actual menu item, it is just a container for hosting the other `TMenuItem` objects.  You would have to loop through those children and clone them individually instead, eg:

```
for I := 0 to PopupMenu1.Items.Count-1 do
  PopupMenu2.Items.Add(CloneMenuItem(PopupMenu1.Items[I]));
```

Comment: Is there a way to detect that a TMenuItem is the root item?  (`TMenuItem.Parent == nil` will do?)